# Adjust tkzKiviatDiagram Diagram axis label size

Tags: tkz-graph, tkz-kiviat

I am trying to display several Kivat diagrams on a single A4 page. For that reason, I have embedded them in subfigures under one figure. This is why I have rescaled the Kivat diagram to fit in one page. However, I noticed that while all the components get scaled down, the axis labels do not and stay on a fixed font size. Following is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[t!] % "[t!]" placement specifier just for this example
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagramFromFile[
        scale=.22,
        label distance=.6cm,
        gap  = 1,label space=4, size = 3,  
        lattice = 10]{tableau.dat}

\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = blue,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = blue,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = blue!20]{tableau.dat}{2}
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = red,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = red,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = red!20]{tableau.dat}{1} 
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = green,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = green,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       =  green!20]{tableau.dat}{3} 
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = orange,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = orange,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       =  orange!20]{tableau.dat}{4} 
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = pink,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = pink,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       =  pink!20]{tableau.dat}{5} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{First subfigure} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}
```

The result gives me something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to decrease the size of the 7 axis labels (Inform, motivate develop adherence ...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! What happens if you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]` instead of `\begin{tikzpicture}`? Or ` `\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={scale=0.5,transform shape}]`? It is hard to test these suggestions since you do not provide us with compilable code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can put `\small` after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.